# Building form and saving as a content type

Tags: 7, entities, webforms

I have designed a site. In this site there is a content type for our experts. Also we need to design a form to employ more experts. We need people send form and admin see their forms, edit and then publish as our content type. Problem is, webform is not suitable for this. Is it possible using CCK as a webform? Is there another solution for this? Is it possible saving webform as a content type?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the [workflow module](http://drupal.org/project/workflow). You would create your content type with all of the same fields as your current webform but set it to default 'unpublished.'

Enable the workflow and create new workflow states for 'draft' and 'reviewed'. Set 
your actions to mark it in draft when the node is created by the user and then allow your editors to approve and publish.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is any expert could send many pages. But one page for any expert is possible. This page is like their profile and used with view module.

Comment: I don't understand your question - are you trying to limit the number of submissions each user can make (which is easier to do in webform obviously)?

Comment: I want to every expert submit his profile. These submissions obviously should be limited. He could edit its profile when he log in and admin could publish his profile as node and use this profile in a table list view.

Answer (score 0):

`Maestro module` provides the `workflow control` for `drupal`,For your content you are free to use `content type` or `web form`
If you are using `content type` no additional module is needed to install but if you are planning to use `web form`
then you have to use `maestro_webform_task` module to integrate your `web form` with `maestro`.Also if you are using `web form` you need to 
provide the permission to different users to see the `web form`.

[Maestro module](https://www.drupal.org/project/maestro)